# How to reduce/remove memory leaks in Angular application

Tags: angularjs, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I am optimizing my large `Angular App`. As I found a that `Google DevTools` is very good to detect problems. As I just have started learning about `DevTools`, I am very confused about memory leaks.

When I move back and from to different pages in my app, Profile heap Snapshot size is increasing again and again so I think there are some object which is not being cleaned by GC and that's why my app is getting slow after sometime so how to solve this. Please help.

**Note**

This is what I understand using DevTools, please correct me if I am wrong. Other suggestions are welcome.

**Till now what I have used**

1. [AngularOnce](https://github.com/tadeuszwojcik/angular-once) directive for reducing watch whenever required.
2. QuickList directive to replace ng-repeat with [quick-ng-repeat](https://github.com/allaud/quick-ng-repeat).
3. [InView](https://github.com/thenikso/angular-inview) Directive, to handle large list so I am removing DOM which is not in viewport.
4. Lazy load approach from [ngInfiniteScroll](http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/) directive.

Comment: Here's a good example of what kind of information you need to give for someone to be able to provide a decent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20654684/how-to-catch-memory-leaks-in-an-angular-application

Comment: An update to this answer -- now that angular 1.3.x is out, you can use the `::` bind-once approach for most cases, instead of adding another dependency to handle this.

Comment: If you are using AngularUI Router, please be aware of its memory leaks too.
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/545

Answer (score 37, accepted):

1. Remove bindings to avoid memory leaks, Use Scopes
   [$destroy()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$destroy) Method.

   **Note:**

   > The most likely culprit of memory leak in Angular is JQuery used in
   >   your directives. If you attach an event-listener in your directive
   >   using a JQuery plugin, the latter would keep a reference to your DOM
   >   even after Angular deletes its own reference to the DOM, which means
   >   it would never be garbage-collected by the browser, which in turn
   >   means “**Detached DOM tree**” in your memory

   In your Directive keep practice for unbinding the jQuery Event. 
   $destory Method which can be used to clean up DOM bindings before an
   element is removed from the DOM.

   ```
    $scope.$on("$destroy",function() {
       $( window ).off( "resize.Viewport" );
    });
   ```
2. Don't Forget To Cancel $timeout Timers In Your $destroy Events In
   AngularJS

   ```
   $scope.$on("$destroy",function( event ) {
       $timeout.cancel( timer );
   });
   ```

Comment: And [here](http://blog.cycle-interactive.com/?p=524) is the full article you mentioned.

Comment: The linky has suffered from link-rot and site is defunct, however, [Wayback](https://web.archive.org/web/20150914164040/http://blog.cycle-interactive.com/?p=524) has this archived.