# Angular.js memory leaks, when should I start worrying

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, memory-leaks

So I have this rather large application built on angular, alot of nested states, alot of directives, data tables and stuff.

We recently decided to switch to full single page, instead of having few small single apps sections(say articles, people, dashboard were each a small single page app previously), so I started dealing with performance a bit more. In chrome you don't visually notice a thing, on firefox on the other hand I THINK it becomes slower over time.

So I started with three snapshot technique to see what's up. But I'm not entirely sure what to make of it.

[**IMAGE**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwa5C.png)
[image]
[image]

- snapshot size doubles its size each snapshot taken(1st 15mb, 2nd 67mb, 3rd 120mb), does this mean anything?
- there's a LOT of red dom, 4000 of red divs for example

Now I feel that those red divs, spans and anchors are mainly my fault, I'm doing some not-so-usual stuff to render those data tables, using this directive I made, and I also feel that some of heap objects are result of those dom elements not being removed properly.

This is what the table directive essentially does

```
var rows = '<div class="row" ng-repeat="item in items">';

_.each(columns, function(column) {
   // pass cell as a string from $templateCache, instead of having <table-cell type="column.type"> which loaded correct templateUrl depending on what was passed via type attr
   var cellTemplate = $templateCache.get(column.type);
   rows += '<div class="column">' + cellTemplate  + '</div>';
});

rows += '</div>';

// el is from directive link function
el.html(rows);

$compile(el.contents())(scope);
```

Reason why I'm doing this at all is because when I tried to use nested `ng-repeat` for rows and columns and `<table-cell>` directive for cells, it took way too long to render, even with only about 6 columns and 50 rows.

So what I think is happening is that none of those divs inside this table gets removed properly so they keep stacking up everytime this table directive loads.

Now even if I deal with that detached dom tree.. what about all the other stuff, how do I know which I should try and deal with, and which are usual for angular and doesn't really affect the performance?

// edit table directive on plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/1fZi6mVn2jBIGF0Q2a40?p=preview

Comment: Without any context we can't blindly recommend a fix.  A screenshot does not explain what is really going on.  Can you post some relevant code ?

Comment: Edited the question, the thing is, I'm not entirely sure this piece of code is what's causing it..

Comment: Why does this need to be a directive?  Can you show where you use it ?

Comment: Edited the question once more to explain the reason why I'm using this directive.

Comment: ng-repeat removes the row elements from the dom ($animate.leave) and destroys their scopes. This page really helped me: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling

Comment: Yeah ng-repeat might do just that, but I'm telling you that these detached dom objects keep stacking up in the memory, it certainly doesn't feel like it should be happening.

Comment: Could you plunkr that directive to see what's going on? It's quite hard to imagine it in context or to see where it could be leaking.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/1fZi6mVn2jBIGF0Q2a40?p=preview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The leak was actually caused by another, completely harmless looking directive that was used in the header of the table and was doing nothing but creating array of "sort items" and then printing it using ng-repeat.. and what's worse **it was not caused by anything I did inside that directive but by its** `replace: true`.. god knows why, I shall try and reproduce it on plunker and report on github.

Since it was almost impossible to find which part of the app was causing it just by looking at the heap report, I went on and deleted all other parts of the app but the one I suspected was causing it, then I found out it wasn't that one, so I went on and kept readding all others.

Once I found out the real problematic directive, I did the same, kept deleting parts of its code until there was literally nothing inside.

Then it was obvious it was one of directive's options, then I found out replace was causing it.

Answer (score 5):

That directive isn't leaking anything. I forked your plnkr, added way more objects to make it noticeable if that were leaking, and added a button which reloads the table. It waits one second and then populates it again.

Nodes are eliminated and recreated. The steps to try to locate the leaks are:

- Start recording
- Wait 2 seconds
- Press the button
- Wait 10 seconds
- Stop recording

Doing that exactly 3 times (so you have the same state of memory), you'll see that the same memory is being used:

[image]

You can check the forked [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KmqQzwMfpZ8OprbCvdao?p=preview)

After this, I can only try to guess what could be the issue. I'm going to give you a couple of suggestions based on what I discovered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20654684/how-to-catch-memory-leaks-in-an-angular-application).

- Check directives, they are usually the cause. The `frickingTable` doesn't seem to be doing anything harmful in it's own but other customs ones could, even if they're not yours, shit just happens.
- If the table is being populated with some sort of "polling", empty the object before reassigning. So, if you see the forked plnkr, you'll see that I first put `items` to `null` and then assign. That should be the way. In the plnkr I did it for it to be noticeable (that the table is being re-populated) however, I've found that browsers tend to keep references somehow if you don't clean objects/arrays. I clean arrays with `.length = 0` and objects with `null`, that makes all possible references to that object ready to be GCed and won't cause any leaks. This sounds silly, but I've seen it in Angular and also in Backbone so it has to be a browser thing.

I can't really think of anything else without seeing any more code. Hope this points to you in the right direction, leaks are annoying to say the least.

Comment: There's literally nothing else on the page where I'm seeing this happening. Nothing else that isn't on the pages where it's not happening anyway. The only difference between the directive code I posted and the one I actually use is that the transformation happens only after data had been loaded, and that's done via scope. $on().. also the number of those "dead" nodes seems to somewhat match the number of divs in the table(multiplied by how many times I switch states/directive is loaded).. I don't know.

Comment: That sounds like you may be binding a lot of times and that could be causing the issue. If you could update the plunkr or show the real app that'd be useful!

Comment: Well I'm using bindonce(removing it doesn't fix the issue btw), so there's not really any binding(two way that is) at all. And as I said, the only difference is that in my app $compile only runs after the data is available, like so http://plnkr.co/edit/AgEY9DFpDBjPZQG1de2u?p=preview

Comment: I guess the way to go would be removing all elements one by one and see which one is causing the issue..