# Heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory- Angular 4 compilation error after ng serve

Tags: node.js, angular

This error occurs when I give ng serve command. my NODE version is v11.0.0 and NPM version is 6.4.1. I'm using Ubuntu.

I tried various solutions like updating node and npm also updated ng.cmd file as shown below :

> @IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (   "%~dp0\node.exe" 
>   –max_old_space_size=8192 "%~dp0..\@angular\cli\bin\ng" %* ) ELSE (
>   @SETLOCAL   @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%   node 
>   –max_old_space_size=8192 "%~dp0..\@angular\cli\bin\ng" %* )

But this solution is not working for me.

I keep getting the error shown below

```
[25343:0x2993860]   103014 ms: Scavenge 1209.7 (1434.1) -> 1203.9 (1434.1) MB, 6.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.245, current mu = 0.226) allocation failure 
[25343:0x2993860]   103064 ms: Scavenge 1215.7 (1434.1) -> 1210.6 (1434.6) MB, 6.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.245, current mu = 0.226) allocation failure 
[25343:0x2993860]   103119 ms: Scavenge 1222.1 (1434.6) -> 1215.2 (1434.6) MB, 7.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.245, current mu = 0.226) allocation failure 


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x2068d904fb5d]
Security context: 0x38a97bf9d969 <JSObject>
    1: byteLength(aka byteLength) [0xdf8960fb3f9] [buffer.js:524] [bytecode=0x1e5e5154501 offset=204](this=0x11b173e025b1 <undefined>,0x1acdd568e6e9 <Very long string[35847]>,0x38a97bfbc249 <String[4]: utf8>)
    2: arguments adaptor frame: 3->2
    3: fromString(aka fromString) [0x2d0b18994f51] [buffer.js:335] [bytecode=0x1e5e514ef89 offset=74](this=0x11b17...
    enter code here

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x90af00 node::Abort() [ng]
 2: 0x90af4c  [ng]
 3: 0xb05f9e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [ng]
 4: 0xb061d4 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [ng]
 5: 0xf0c6f2  [ng]
 6: 0xf0c7f8 v8::internal::Heap::CheckIneffectiveMarkCompact(unsigned long, double) [ng]
 7: 0xf18f88 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [ng]
 8: 0xf19b1b v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [ng]
 9: 0xf1c851 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [ng]
10: 0xee58b5  [ng]
11: 0xeed1ab v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [ng]
12: 0x103c098 v8::internal::String::SlowFlatten(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::ConsString>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [ng]
13: 0xb03f0b v8::internal::String::Flatten(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [ng]
14: 0xb104d9 v8::String::Utf8Length(v8::Isolate*) const [ng]
15: 0x923e99  [ng]
16: 0xb8d2ca  [ng]
17: 0xb8de65 v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [ng]
18: 0x2068d904fb5d 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Please suggest the solution on this.

Comment: The bulletproof solution is setting up (or increase the space of the) [swap-partion](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#How_do_I_add_or_modify_a_swap_partition.3F) or [swap-file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#How_do_I_add_a_swap_file.3F). It does not solves the problem, but prevents the system crash, so you can start debugging the [root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20654684/how-to-catch-memory-leaks-in-an-angular-application) of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the free memory and also try to reboot nginx server. Sometimes server cache memory acquire lot of space